# iOS / Swift - Unable to set Enum Value on Init()

Tags: ios, swift, enums, init

I created an extension of SKSpriteNode class. I am making brick objects, which have different behavior when they get hit

```
import SpriteKit

class Brick: SKSpriteNode {

    enum type {
        case None, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red
    }

    static let colorMap = [
        Brick.type.Green : UIColor.greenColor(),
        Brick.type.Yellow : UIColor.yellowColor(),
        Brick.type.Orange : UIColor.orangeColor(),
        Brick.type.Red : UIColor.redColor()
    ]

    var brickType = Brick.type.None

    convenience init (size: CGSize, type: Brick.type) {
        self.init(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: size)

        // Here I set the initial type and color
        // The color is assigned just fine, but the brickType
        // variable is still Brick.type.None
        self.setType(type)
    }

    func gotHit () -> Int {
        switch (self.brickType) {
            case Brick.type.Yellow:
                setType(Brick.type.Green);
                break;

            case Brick.type.Orange:
                setType(Brick.type.Yellow);
                break;

            case Brick.type.Red:
                setType(Brick.type.Orange);
                break;

            case Brick.type.Green: // Green
                self.removeFromParent()
                return 1

            default:
                break
        }

        return 0
    }

    func setType (typeToSet: Brick.type) {
        self.brickType = typeToSet // only works when called from gotHit()
        self.color = Brick.colorMap[typeToSet]! // this works everytime
    }
}
```

Then I make an instance of this class:

```
let brickPrototype = Brick(size: CGSizeMake(55, 25), type: Brick.type.Green)
```

My issue is that, despite calling `setType()` inside the `convenience init ()`, the value of the public `brickType` variable is still the default one, `Brick.type.None`. The color is changed without problems, so the argument seems to be passed correctly.

If I set the default `brickType` variable to `Brick.type.Yellow`, and execute the `gotHit()` function, the `setType()` function will effectively change the type of the brick to `Brick.type.Green`, and after calling it again, the node gets deleted from the view by calling `self.removeFromParent()`. Hence I am sure the issue is when I call the function from `convenience init()`, even though I get no errors.

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the object and checking the type?  I just pasted your code into a playground and it worked correctly

Comment: Still works for me in the playground.

Comment: I added a simple "convert the enum to a string function" - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/2010f0474429a679a0b9 and it returns the  appropriate value

Comment: @Paulw11 I added a ``println(self.brickType == Brick.type.None)`` right after I set it inside the ``init()`` method, and it returns false (which is correct). However I add it inside the ``gotHit()`` function and it returns true. Also, just like for you, it works in the playground. But not on my project.

Comment: @Paulw11 I noticed inside ``setType`` function, that the ``.color`` and ``.brickType`` property references have different syntax highlighting. I searched the quick help and found out that color has a declaration of ``var color: UIColor { get set }`` while the brickType has a declaration of ``var brickType: Brick.type`` (no get/set). Maybe the issue is somewhere around there?

Comment: I noticed that you are saying `brickPrototype` in your code - Are you correctly instantiating multiple bricks or are you trying to re-use a single brick object (assuming your have more than one brick in your game).

Comment: @Paulw11 I put the brickPrototype into a loop, and create many instances of it using ``brickPrototype.copy()``

Comment: Hmm.  Try instantiating the bricks directly in the loop instead of copying.

Comment: @Paulw11 so it seems it was the ``copy()`` function the one doing all this trouble. Creating each instance separatedly did the trick. But out of curiosity, wouldn't this be bad performance-wise? are there any other alternatives to ``copy()``? Thank you!

Comment: I would imagine that the performance would be identical.  It is better to write clear code and then analyse/address performance where required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to have a default value if you set it for the first time in the initializer. Haven't tested this to see if it fixes your issue, but I did clean up the code a bit.

```
class Brick: SKSpriteNode {

enum BrickColorType: UInt {
    case Red
    case Orange
    case Yellow
    case Green //This order matters for nextColor

    func color() -> UIColor {
        switch self {
        case Green:
            return .greenColor() //Swift does not need break statements in cases.
        case Yellow:
            return .yellowColor()
        case Orange:
            return .orangeColor()
        case Red:
            return .redColor()
        }
    }

    func nextColor() -> BrickColorType? {
        return BrickColorType(rawValue: self.rawValue.successor()) //If self = green, this will return nil.
    }

}

var brickType: BrickColorType {
    didSet {
        self.color = brickType.color()
    }
}

init (size: CGSize, type: BrickColorType) {
    brickType = type
    super.init(texture: nil, color: .whiteColor(), size: size) //Because the earlier one was a convenience init and Xcode was complaining
    self.color = brickType.color() //Because didSet is not called in initializer
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { //This is just boilerplate required to inherit from any NSObject
    brickType = .Red //Or whatever else. If you really want to add a None case to the enum, might I suggest instead making brickType optional?
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func gotHit () -> Int { //Consider making this a Bool

    if let next = self.brickType.nextColor() {
        //There is a valid next color
        brickType = next
        return 0
    }

    //There is no valid next color
    self.removeFromParent()
    return 1

}
} //Weird formatting because of StackOverflow
```